# R: How to customize the alpha.values in performance in package ROCR

Tags: r, roc

How to customize the alpha.values in performance in package ROCR? It seems that the `perf@alpha.values` are automatically set and cannot be changed. Please see the following code.

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
pred
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
perf@alpha.values[[1]] # Inf 0.9910964 0.9846673 0.9845992 0.9834944 0.9706413
```